# How to build cmake project for Android from terminal with Qt > 5.14

Tags: android, qt, cmake, cross-compiling, qt5.15

I can have download Qt source from git and checkout it to 5.15.2  and compiled it for android. I have created kit of it in Qt Creator and it successfully builds my app.
But How can I do this in terminal without qt creator

I have tried following:-

```sh
export QT_ROOT=/home/noone/Development/KDE/Qt/build/installation

cmake .. -GNinja \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:String=Release \
    -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=$QT_ROOT/bin/qmake \
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:STRING=/home/noone/untitled1/build/installation \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING=$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ \
    -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL:STRING=16 \
    -DANDROID_NDK:PATH=$ANDROID_NDK \
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:PATH=$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
    -DANDROID_ABI:STRING=armeabi-v7a \
    -DANDROID_SDK:PATH=$ANDROID_HOME \
    -DANDROID_STL:STRING=c++_shared \
    -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH:PATH=$QT_ROOT
```

but it gives following error:-

```
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /optHDD/AndroidNDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ECM" (requested
  version 5.74) with any of the following names:

    ECMConfig.cmake
    ecm-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "ECM" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ECM_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "ECM" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/noone/untitled1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

here is my CMakeLists.txt:-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(untitled1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# QtCreator supports the following variables for Android, which are identical to qmake Android variables.
# Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html for more information.
# They need to be set before the find_package(Qt5 ...) call.

#if(ANDROID)
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
#    if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
#        set(ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libcrypto.so
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libssl.so)
#    endif()
#endif()

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)

if(ANDROID)
    add_library(untitled1 SHARED
      main.cpp
      qml.qrc
    )
else()
    add_executable(untitled1
      main.cpp
      qml.qrc
    )
endif()

target_compile_definitions(untitled1
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(untitled1
  PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Quick)
```